# How to fix error "ERROR_CAMERA_DISABLED" on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2

I'm developing an Android application using Kotlin and Android Studio that opens the camera and initiates a setRepeatingRequest.
The application uses "CameraDevice.StateCallback", "CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback" and "ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener".

If I keep the screen on, the app never crashes.
If I lock the screen, or let it lock, after about a minute I get the error "ERROR_CAMERA_DISABLED" twice [1].

Is there anything I need to do to not get the error?

[1]: I set "onError" on "CameraDevice.StateCallback" to print the error code and the string "onError", and I see the message twice in Logcat, like so:

```
MyCamera    com.example.app3    D  3
MyCamera    com.example.app3    D  onError
MyCamera    com.example.app3    D  3
MyCamera    com.example.app3    D  onError
```

I tried to see if something was being garbage collected by defining "finalize" functions, but to no avail.

Comment: Could this question maybe help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292039/camera-not-working-when-lock-screen-and-return